# 'Aggregate' function not working in mongodb with using lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

'Aggregate' function not working in mongodb with using lookup. can you please help me out from this situation.i tried many times also remove group . condition. but it cant's works.

```
db.faq_feedback.aggregate(
   {
      "project": {
         "question_id": 1,
         "yes": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$feedback", "yes"] }, 1, 0] },
         "no": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$feedback", "no"] }, 1, 0] }
      },
      "group": {
         "_id": "$question_id",
         "yes": { "$sum": "$yes" },
         "no": { "$sum": "$no" }
      },
      "lookup":
         [{
            "from": "faq",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "faq"
         }],
      "unwind": "$faq",
      "match": { "faq.lang": "en" },
      "limit": 100,
      "skip": 0,
      "sort": { "no": -1 }
   }
)
```

---

Comment: Is this your real code? All the pipelines have wrong syntax. For example `"unwind": "$faq"` must be `{$unwind: "$faq"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on mongo shell.

```
db.faq_feedback.aggregate([
{
    "$project": {
         "question_id": 1,
         "yes": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$feedback", "yes"] }, 1, 0] },
         "no": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$feedback", "no"] }, 1, 0] }
      }
},
{"$group": {
         "_id": {question_id:"$question_id"},
         "yes": { "$sum": "$yes" },
         "no": { "$sum": "$no" }
      }
},
{
    "$lookup":
         {
            "from": "faq",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "faq"
         },
},
{ "$unwind": "$faq"},
{"$match": { "faq.lang": "en" }},
{"$limit": 100},
 {"$skip": 0}
     { "$sort": { "no": -1 }}
])
```

Comment: "$lookup":
         {
            "from": "faq",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "faq"
         }

i think problem in "lookup ", i have two collection "faq" , "faq_feedback"

Comment: by default lookup giving `faq_feedback` vs `faq` collection

Comment: all good but i think problem in  {"$group": {
         "_id": {question_id:"$question_id"},
         "yes": { "$sum": "$yes" },
         "no": { "$sum": "$no" }
      }
}